# Excel, many-to-one query with multiple nested IF statement

Tags: excel

I have two excel sheets A and B in Excel 2010. I need to add information from B to A if multiple criteria are met. The criteria are as follows: for each row in SheetA, find the first row in SheetB that matches the following:  1) if NameA = NameB (there are multiple repeats of names in both NameA and NameB in each sheet, 2) if Col2 in SheetA is > Col 2 in SheetB and 3) if Col2 in SheetA is < Col3 in SheetB. If all these criteria are met, then put SheetB Col4 value in Col4 of SheetA and move to next row in SheetA to repeat, otherwise move through each row in SheetB until query met or no matches found (in which case, put in ‘0’). In the image (at link '1'), I would want ‘2’ to be put in SheetA D2, for example (from SheetB D3). Does anyone know a way to do this? Thanks![1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcI2P.jpg)

Comment: Use INDEX/MATCH with multiple criteria.  This has been answered on this site and many other many times.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Why not take your new dupe-hammer out for some exercise? Surely you have an appropriate answer that can be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @ScottCraner - I could not find the answer though I did look! More specifically, here is the formula that I have attempted but only get #N/A when I expand it to include the third criteria through the AND function:

Comment: You do not use the AND you put it in line with a `*`.  Array formulas do not like the `AND`